# _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i got an error and this is my API wrapper

```
    if (method == "get") {
      var param = '';

      Map<String, dynamic> params =
          data['params'] != null ? data['params'] : {};
      params.forEach((k, v) => param += k + "=" + (v == null ? '' : v) + "&");
      try {
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        dio.options.headers = headers;
        final response = await dio.get(url + "?" + param);
        responseJson = _response(response);
        //print('Response ' + response.data.toString());
      } on SocketException {
        throw FetchDataException('Tidak terhubung ke server');
      }
  . . .
```

and this is the repository:

```
  Future<LeaveListModel> fetchResponse(query) async {
    final response = await _wrapper.apiRequest(
        "get", _wrapper.leaveListGetData, {'params': query}, true);
    return LeaveListModel.fromJson(response);
  }
```

this is the service, in case you wanted to know:

```
class Service {
  GetStorage localData = GetStorage();

  final String initial = "Service";
  final String baseUrl = ConstantConfig().leaveListEndPoint;
  final String appCode = ConstantConfig().leaveListAppCode;
  final String outputType = "json";
  final String routeAuthConnect = "auth/connect/";
  final String routeAuthGetAccessToken = "auth/getAccessToken/";

  final String leaveListGetData = "list/";

  Future<dynamic> apiRequest(
      String method, String route, Map<String, dynamic> data,
      [bool needToken = false]) async {
    ApiWrapper _apiWrapper = ApiWrapper();
    if (needToken) {
      int thisTime = (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).round();
      String? savedExpired = localData.read(initial + KeyStorage.accessExpired);
      int expire = savedExpired == null ? 0 : int.parse(savedExpired);
      if (expire < thisTime) {
        dynamic tokenResponse = await _apiWrapper.request(baseUrl, initial,
            appCode, outputType, 'post', routeAuthGetAccessToken, {});
        await localData.write(initial + KeyStorage.accessToken,
            tokenResponse['response']['access_token']);
        return await _apiWrapper.request(
            baseUrl, initial, appCode, outputType, method, route, data);
      } else {
        return await _apiWrapper.request(
            baseUrl, initial, appCode, outputType, method, route, data);
      }
    } else {
      return await _apiWrapper.request(
          baseUrl, initial, appCode, outputType, method, route, data);
    }
  }
}
```

i just want to call a json file but it show an error, i don't know what's wrong with my code, in case you know how to fix it please let me know

this is the error:

```
  I/flutter (20696): Call https:xxxxxxxxxxxx
   I/flutter (20696): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

another error note:

```
I/flutter ( 7626): {}
I/flutter ( 7626): 1
I/flutter ( 7626): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
I/flutter ( 7626): {}
I/flutter ( 7626): 1
I/flutter ( 7626): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

actually that shows that the process is stopped on `Map<String, dynamic> params = data['params'] != null ? data['params'] : {};` because i try to debug the API wrapper with `print('1');`, `print('2');`, `print('3');` just to show where the process stop and getting error

Comment: What does your error say and which line does it point at?

Comment: im already write the error on the post title

Comment: check your line in which the debugger is pointing at. Is it in 'responseJson = _response(response);' or 'Map<String, dynamic> params =
          data['params'] != null ? data['params'] : {};'

Comment: im added the snipped code from my repository, can you pointing out which code that contains error?

Comment: responseJson = _response(response);
Probably this is where the code breaks. Add your '_response' function. Are you decoding the json response you are getting?

Comment: yes im decoding it into api responses which was the switch case of the api http response code, like 202 101 100 and so on

Comment: First, are you converting the response with _jsonDecode()_? If yes, then I would advice that  you declare the variable _Map<dynamic, dynamic>_ or for short _Map_ instead of _Map<String, dynamic>_.

Comment: could you add your api response? @fairycatto

Comment: my api response is inside repository

Comment: im already change the Map<dynamic, dynamic> into Map<string, dynamic> but the api status is loading -> error instead of loading -> complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `decode` your response first then use it:

```
LeaveListModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response));
```

also I think you are passing `query` encoded to `ApiWrapper`, so you need to decode it like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> params = data['params'] != null ? jsonDecode(data['params']) : {};
```

Comment: @fairycatto was it what you want?

Comment: it's not, actually im already add the jsonDecode to the response but it still doesn't fix it

Comment: where do you do that? I can't see in you code!

Comment: yesterday, im already try to fix it with jsonDecode but still the reponse shows error

Comment: it still doesn't work, im already edit this post and add a file that might be related to the work, in case you know what's wrong with these all

Comment: could you add _apiWrapper?

Comment: this is the apiWrapper file https://wtools.io/paste-code/bH4H

Comment: the print("response = $response"); doesn't show, but im already edit the post and add the reason why it doesn't appear on console so you can understand the reason why, [i add it on the bottom of the post page]

Comment: could you print data before that line that error happened?

Comment: it shows I/flutter ( 7626): {params: {}} after I print data

Comment: and also can you tell me where is this `query ` come from in this line: final response = await _wrapper.apiRequest(
        "get", _wrapper.leaveListGetData, {'params': query}, true);?

Comment: i think you're right, it's from {'params': query}, and when i delete {'params': query} and change it into {}, the error alert of " type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' " was gone, but the code response is still showing error instead of complete because the StreamBuilder<dynamic> didn't read any data

Comment: now can you show me the result of print("response = $response"); before return LeaveListModel.fromJson(response); ?

Comment: yes, the result of print("response = $response"); is {params: {}} when i fill it with {'params': query} and null when i delete the {'params': query} and change it into {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249945/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-fairycatto).

Comment: hello, are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

```
return LeaveListModel.fromJson(response);
```

It seems to me that you should use `response.data` here, instead of response.

```
return LeaveListModel.fromJson(response.data);
```

Comment: sorry, it still doesn't work, im already edit this post and add a file that might be related to the work, in case you know what's wrong with these all

Comment: could you share _response(response) this method. Also your model class please

Comment: sure, here the model https://wtools.io/paste-code/bH4E , and here the response https://wtools.io/paste-code/bH4D , actually the response is only the response code when it trying to connect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic>.from(yourData)
```